# Serialized array of relations to Laravel relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm facing one problem and I can't find the perfect and best optimized solution.
So I'm kindly asking for your opinion.
Here's what bothering me.
I've got a serialized array from DB that looks like this:

```
a:6:{s:13:"property_type";s:1:"1";s:16:"property_feature";a:2:{i:0;s:1:"3";i:1;s:1:"4";}s:19:"property_offer_type";s:1:"5";s:19:"property_built_type";a:1:{i:0;s:2:"10";}s:24:"properties_office_phones";s:2:"13";s:15:"property_labels";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"8";}}
```

Here is the non-serialized version for more clarity:

```
Array(
[property_type] => 1
[property_feature] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 4
    )

[property_offer_type] => 5
[property_built_type] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10

    )

[properties_office_phones] => 13
[property_labels] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
    ))
```

All of this keys values are stored in one single table.

This is how the table looks like:

```
ID  |   Name        | Slug        | .. etc
1   | A name here   | a-name-here | .. other
```

What do you think will be the best and most optimized way to get the information related to those IDs using Laravel 8 relations, so it can be retrieved as relations just like "with()" is doing.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are the id of the table linked to the serialized data? and are you using mysql?

Comment: Hi. The column ID is = IDs written in the array. Yes I'm using mySQL.

Comment: Hmm... but to get it working with laravel you would need to put it in tables, would it suffice to migrate the data to tables?

Comment: The thing I need is when I call: 
$test = Property::whereHas('OfferType', fn($q) => $q->where('slug', 'sale'))->with('OfferType', 'City', 'Region', 'PropertyFeatures')->get();
to get the data from the table and replace the IDs with it.

Comment: I can only think of migrating the arrays from json to sql would be the option, is that fitting?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Could you give me details or example. Thx :)

Comment: Make tables and insert rows into your database instead of having an serialized array

Comment: Ah. Ok. I got it. Yes maybe this will be the final solution. Now I'm doing it with 2 for loops and I'm not sure this is the bet way.